# Unity3d C# Math.Clamp does not return max value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game character will lose hunger when he moved. I tried to use `Mathf.Clamp` to limit the number when the player consumed food which will add 20 hunger to the `HungerClock` so it doesn't go more than 100. The problem I have is the number in HUD will not display the number that's more than a hundred but the system will stored the number that goes up to 100. So when the number is below 100 the hud will start updating the number.

This is part of my code:

```
    private float HungerClock;      
    private float ThirstClock;   
    private float MaxHunger = 100.0f;   
    private float MinHunger = 0.0f;    
    private float HungerStatus;

void Start ()   
    {       
        thePlayer = GetComponent<Player> ();
        health = thePlayer.ReturnHealth ();
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        HungerClock = thePlayer.ReturnHunger();
    }

void Update () {        
        HungerStatus = Mathf.Clamp(HungerStatus, MinHunger, MaxHunger);
        HungerClock = Mathf.Clamp(HungerClock, MinHunger, MaxHunger);

        PlayerHUD.updateHunger(HungerStatus);
        PlayerHUD.updateThirst(ThirstStatus);

        if(sceneName == ("Bunker"))             
        {
            HungerStatus = 100.0f;
            ThirstStatus = 100.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            //Hunger and thirst counter-----------------------------

            HungerStatus = HungerClock - distanceTravelled * 0.5f;
            ThirstStatus = ThirstClock - distanceTravelled * 0.5f;
            distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
            lastPosition = transform.position;

            //------------------------------------------------------
        }       
    }

public void ChangeHunger(float change)    
    {
        HungerClock += change;
        // I tried to put Mathf.Clamp here but it did not work either.
    }
```

HUD Script

```
public void updateHunger (float Hunger) 
{
    //Hunger = Player.ReturnHunger();
    hungerTextMesh.text = hungerText + Hunger;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. What do you expect your code to do, and what is it currently doing?

Comment: I want my hunger to not go over 100 when i use an item that will add 20 to it. and it's going over 100 but doesn't update in HUD. I will add my HUD function. for example 90+20 = 110 but it will not display 110.i want it to be 90+20 = 100

Comment: Add your updateHunger and updateThirst functions please.

Comment: Can You check values of `health = thePlayer.ReturnHealth ();
        HungerClock = thePlayer.ReturnHunger();`  in Start function, is update properly?

Answer (score 1):

It is going over 100 because you told it to.

You have written:

1. clamp the value
2. change the value
3. display in HUD
4. *change the value again*

So ... now the value in HUD and the value in the game are different.. And the HUD will never go above 100 because you clamped it (step 1), but the game will go above 100 because you changed it without clamping it (step 4)

Comment: I tried HungerStatus = Mathf.Clamp((HungerClock - distanceTravelled * 0.5f) , MinHunger, MaxHunger)) and it's not working in the right way.

Comment: OK, so post what values you put in, what value came out. We cannot mind-read. You have to give us the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other responders tackled this with more thought. And @Adam above actually mentioned it, but to elaborate on his solution, try this:

```
void Update () {
    if(sceneName == ("Bunker"))             
    {
        HungerStatus = 100.0f;
        ThirstStatus = 100.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        //Hunger and thirst counter-----------------------------

        HungerStatus = HungerClock - distanceTravelled * 0.5f;
        ThirstStatus = ThirstClock - distanceTravelled * 0.5f;
        distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
        lastPosition = transform.position;

        //------------------------------------------------------
    }

    HungerStatus = Mathf.Clamp(HungerStatus, MinHunger, MaxHunger);
    HungerClock = Mathf.Clamp(HungerClock, MinHunger, MaxHunger);

    PlayerHUD.updateHunger(HungerStatus);
    PlayerHUD.updateThirst(ThirstStatus);   
}
```

Notice the change in order of statements. We are now using the Mathf.Clamp() after all the other processing.
I hope that helps!

Comment: thank you! now the number will not go more than 100 but it still doesn't max it's value when added a number. for example  96+20 it will stay on 96. is there anyway i can make it fill up to 100?

Comment: I recommend following some sample game-tutorials online- I think they would help you understand programming logic in Unity better :)

Anyhow, to deal with your current problem...
I'm a little confused between your variables `HungerStatus` and `HungerClock`. Which one represents the player's current hunger?
And what does the `PlayerHUD.updateHunger()` method do?

Comment: This is a playerstatemachine script. Hungerstatus is the place that stored the Hungerstatus. HungerClock will get the hunger's value from the other script. HUD function will updated the number and represent on a HUD.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what is going on with the information provided here. I suggest adding `Debug.Log(...)`s at different parts of your code to see where the value is being changes against your intention.
Good luck!